# Get first available AsyncResult

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have several async methods (Annotatad @Asynchronous) Returning Future Objects. I have to execute them at once but it would be enough for me to get the result of the first one which ready, is there any nice and safe solutions for that that works on a Java EE container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard API for this facility. Just check [`Future#isDone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#isDone()) yourself in an infinite loop on the current thread in an utility method which look like below:

```
public static <T> Future<T> getFirstDone(List<Future<T>> futures) {
    while (true) {
        for (Future<T> future : futures) {
            if (future.isDone()) {
                return future;
            }
        }

        // Break if necessary infinite loop here once it reaches certain timeout.
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<Future<Foo>> results = collectThemSomehow();
Future<Foo> firstDoneResult = getFirstDone(results);
// ...
```

Comment: Yeah it seems to be the best solution in that case, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how it can works with Spring. In this example, the asynchronous job simply returns a boolean.

```
public void example(Job job) throws Exception
{
    Future<Boolean> executor = jobExecutor.doJob(job);

    //wait to be done
    while (!executor.isDone()) {
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }

    System.out.println(executor.get());
}
```

The job executor class is annoted @Component.

```
@Async
public Future<Boolean> doJob(Job job) throws Exception { 
    boolean isSuccessful;
    //do something
    return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(isSuccessful);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I also did something similar but I was wondering if there is any better solution, a wrapper class, some kind of pool /executer etc where I can collect several Future tasks and receive the first one as it is ready.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can invert it - transfer function pointer to async method and call it:

```
  AtomicBoolean executed = new AtomicBoolean(false);
  Runnable r = () ->{
        if(!executed.getAndSet(true)){
            //do job
        }
  };
```

But be careful: this code is executed inside worker thread, not original thread.